# Unable to post HTTP request from Ionic application

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic2, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to login to my application hosted locally(for now) using ionic framework.

This is my nodejs backend code for logging in which was meant for web application but now I am making it for android platfrom as well

```
// process the login form
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect: '/login', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
    failureFlash: true // allow flash messages
}));
```

HTML code in ionic

```
    <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

The login function which is called:

```
login() {
this.http.post('10.222.103.169:8080/login', JSON.stringify({ email: this.email, password: this.password }))
    .map((response: Response) => {

        let user = response.json();
        console.log(user);
        if (user && user.token) {
            // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        }
    }
}
```

if I use .subscribe method for the post it gives an error
other login method:

```
login() {
    this.http.post('10.222.103.169:8080/login', JSON.stringify({ email: this.email, password: this.password }))
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

> Runtime Error Error in ./LoginPage class LoginPage - caused by: Failed
>   to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL

but the link is correct and works
now the problem is that it's not even sending the post request to the server.

PS: I am new to angular2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it as shown below.This is the Angular way of `post` method.Hope code is self explanatory.If you need any help feel free to comment below.

```
      //login
      loginUser(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('content-type', 'application/json');
        let body = { email: email, password: password };
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let url = this.authenticationEndPoint + encodeURI(username) + '&password=' + encodeURI(password);

        return this.http.post(url, body, options)
          .map(this.extractData)
          .catch(this.handleError);
      }

 //to extract data
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  //to handle error
  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, no request on backend or any error message pops up

Comment: nothing is showing up, in console neither it is sending the request to backend.
also instead of `let url = this.authenticationEndPoint + encodeURI(username) + '&password=' + encodeURI(password);` I tried `let url = this.authenticationEndPoint`  as I am already sending the login credentails with the body paramenter in post request

Comment: though `$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://10.222.103.169:8080/login",
  data: { email: "myemail", password: "wdwd" },
  success: function() {
    console.log("success");
  }
});` this seems to work

Comment: yes you have to send a javascript object there.no need to use `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: not sure when its authenticating with jquery post method why it's not working with angular post method

Comment: after using .subscribe method I am getting
` Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.` error

Comment: hope you're very close.try to install this extension and enable it.https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139139/discussion-between-warl0ck-and-sampath).

Answer (score 0):

Assign the params to a URLSearchParams object

```
 login() {
 let params = new URLSearchParams;
params.append('email',this.email);
params.append('password',this.password);
    this.http.post('10.222.103.169:8080/login',search:params )
        .map((response: Response) => {
            let user = response.json();
            console.log(user);
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: in post request will URLSearchParams be feasible ?